# Application Color schemes

Tags: user-interface, colors

I am working on a new UI for an existing application, currently in VB6, and have been told to make it look better / pretty.

Is there anywhere I can get some good ideas around colour schemes for a business application which are not 25 shades of grey?

FYI: I am working in WPF.

Comment: Maybe you're question would be more suitable at: http://ui.stackexchange.com/. Even then, I'd say you'll want to provide a little more detail than what you gave here

Comment: Use some online color scheme designer like http://www.colorhunter.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this [application](http://ColorSchemeDesigner.com) (for taking color scheme)
[this](http://www.pictaculous.com/) application is for taking color scheme from a photo
[this](http://www.writedesignonline.com/resources/design/rules/color.html) is article about color theory so as [this](http://www.colormatters.com/colortheory.html)
And those are css galleries for inspiration:
http://www.bestcssgallery.com/
http://www.cssheaven.com/
http://www.cssdaddy.com/
http://www.csselite.com/

you can also search for "graphic design" "user interface design" "UI design" "web design" "css design" on google image search.

Answer (score 5):

You asked for Color Schemes.

Here it is: http://kuler.adobe.com/