# Which colors go well together?

Tags: user-interface, colors, usability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application Color schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606328/application-color-schemes)

Is there a tutorial of sorts that covers which colors go well together? That is, color mixing that will increase usability and consumer appeal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this website out

http://colorschemedesigner.com/

It basically has the most common color schemes used. It also gives you the percentage of the population who will not be able to see the current selected colors (which is really cool!).