# Are there conventions on which color combinations go well together?

Tags: colors, terminal, terminal-color

Most terminal color palettes have colorschemes that are customizable.
Many terminal users make use of some standard colorscheme such as solarized.

I'm building a terminal application that needs to use colors.
My question is, how do I know which color combinations from the terminal color palette go well together?
For instance, in the colorschemes that I use, the last color in the palette generally serves well as an alternative background color, but I couldn't afford the risk that some text is hardly visible for someone else because of his different colorscheme.

Are there any conventions on this?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494328/which-colors-go-well-together?rq=1

Comment: @Thilo no that's different. I'm talking about terminal color palettes